# Searchkick pagination, limit and offset issues, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, pagination, kaminari, searchkick

i want to display the 3 last looks in the first row, then i want to display all others but without the 3 lasts looks.

This is my code

```
def index
    query = params[:query].presence || "*"
    conditions = {}
    conditions[:available] = true
    conditions[:look_tags] = params[:look_tags] if params[:look_tags].present?
    @last_3_looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, limit: 3
    @looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, page: params[:page], per_page: 8
end
```

the problem is if i put offset like below, i've got the same 8 looks at every pages, how to handle that please ?

```
@looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, page: params[:page], per_page: 8, offset: 3
end
```

Answer (score 1):

simply exclude the first 3 results from the @looks (check 6th line)

```
query = params[:query].presence || "*"
conditions = {}
conditions[:available] = true
conditions[:look_tags] = params[:look_tags] if params[:look_tags].present?
@last_3_looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, limit: 3
conditions[:id] = { not: @last_3_looks.results.collect(&:id) }
@looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, page: params[:page], per_page: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to calculate the offset, something like:

```
  page = params[:page].to_i
  per_page = 8
  starting_offset = 3
  offset = starting_offset + ((page - 1) * per_page)

  @looks = Look.search query, where: conditions, order: { created_at: :desc }, page: page, per_page: per_page, offset: offset
```

But you can also consider using [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-padding-scope) gem which will make the calculation for you.
Seems like Searchkick [allows that](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#pagination).

Also, see this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240015/14367221).

Comment: thanks, i tried your code but it doenst work, i'm already using kaminari. Wen is use offset on searchick it removed the last 3 looks, but when i change page it show again and again the same looks per page ....
i just want the offset on the Look.all => just remove 3 looks then display 8 looks per page

Comment: Can you tell me what doesn't work? What's the error?
Also, does your page count starts at 1? (or maybe at 0?)

Comment: Ok i'm trying to explain the simpliest (sorry for my english) : 
- On Look#index, only on page 1 i want to display the 3 newest looks, represented by "@last_3_looks" (works fine)
-then i dont want to have these 3 looks in "@looks", and want to display 8 looks per page with kaminari, the problem is if i put offset: 3 in the query, they are no longer here but if i go to next page it's always the same 8 looks displaying, if i move it i still have the 3 last looks in "@looks", but pagination works fine...
very struggling ....